# How to get all model parameters from Freemarker parser tree?

Tags: java, freemarker

Case:
when I am applying an FTL template in my system, I want to resolve all the model params from the template? so that users can know to pass these parameters instead of reading the whole template.

Eg:

```sql
SELECT
    platform
FROM
(
<#list tableList as table>
    SELECT
            __time,
            platform
    FROM
    ${table}
    <#if table_has_next>UNION ALL</#if>
</#list>
)
WHERE
__time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '${startTime}' AND '${endTime}'
GROUP BY
    1
```

After calling a method can output the format:

```json
{
   "startTime" : "",
   "endTime": "",
   "tableList": null
}
```

I tried the rootElement which was generated by JavaCC in the Freemaker core, but it's not public, and throw an error.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Not related to the question, but instead of `<#if table_has_next>UNION ALL</#if>` you can write `<#sep>UNION ALL`. (Even `table_has_next` is legacy, and the preferred for is `table?has_next`.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature for that.

In general, it's impossible to tell with static analysis what variables will be needed. The template language is too dynamic for that. Like what if you see reading of variable `x` somewhere, and there's also `<#assign x = ...>` somewhere in the template. Now you need to be able to prove that it's always executed before reading `x`, otherwise `x` has to be set before template execution. Then there are `#include`-s, global variables, etc.